# How to POST single value as request body using axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, post, axios

I have an POST API as:

- URL: `/get-item`
- Method: `POST`
- Request Body: `id(Integer)`

I know it's little weird to have a single value as request body instead of query or path parameter but it is what it is.

Now I am trying to call the API from my `React App` using below code.

```js
export const axiosInstance = axios.create(AXIOS_BASE_CONFIG);
// ...

const loadMyItem = async (itemId) => {
    console.log("itemId:: ", itemId);
    setLoading(true);
    axiosInstance.post(
      URL_GetMyItem,
      itemId
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log("res", res);
      setMyItem(res?.result);
    }).catch((err) => {
      errorHandler(err);
    }).finally(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }
```

But getting Bad Request error.

Response:

```json
{"timestamp":"...","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/.../get-item"}
```

How to call a POST API having single value as Request Body using axios?

Comment: What request content-type does the API expect? Does the documentation offer any examples?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Axios will detect that your `itemId` payload is a primitive (string / number), stringify it and send it with `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The issue there is that the stringified version of an integer is not a valid format for this header.

You will need to customise the content-type header and send the value as JSON

```js
axiosInstance
  .post(URL_GetMyItem, JSON.stringify(itemId), {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    setMyItem(data.result);
  })
  .catch(errorHandler)
  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
```

An alternative I highly recommend is the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which isn't so opinionated and more stable

```js
fetch(new URL(URL_GetMyItem, AXIOS_BASE_CONFIG.baseURL), {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(itemId),
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Request failed: ${URL_GetMyItem}`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    setMyItem(data.result);
  })
  .catch(errorHandler)
  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
```

Comment: Thankyou @Phil for the reply.
Getting `"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type"` for `"content-type": "text/plain"` and `"status":400,"error":"Bad Request"` for `"content-type": "application/json"`.
I am able to get the response from postman though using `row` + `JSON(application/json)`.

Comment: @Prem well you didn't answer my question above... what does the API expect? Without knowing it's impossible to answer and I've obviously misinterpreted the requirements you listed. Possibly you have too

Comment: it expects a single integer value as whole request body.

`getMyItem(@RequestBody Long itemId)`

The above line is code snippet of method signature from API backend.

Comment: @Prem Looks like Spring. Is it?

Comment: Yes, spring is in backend.

Comment: @Prem I think for that you have to force it to be JSON. Have updated my answer

Comment: Stick with @Phil's answer for axios with "content-type": "application/json", but try taking out the JSON.stringify(itemId) in favour of itemId as-is because stringify is putting the itemId in quotes so it is a String not a Long, causing the 400.

Comment: @JohnWilliams no, it does not add quotes. AFAIK, OP has not tried my last update.

Comment: JSON.stringify() on an int adds quotes. Try it here - https://jsonformatter.org/json-stringify-online?utm_content=cmp-true

Comment: @JohnWilliams no, it most certainly does not ~ https://jsfiddle.net/rjhv1ypb/. Don't confuse a string representation with a string with embedded quotes